# How to dynamically store the countdown timer value in a webpage to database using php?

Tags: php, ajax

I am creating a online examination portal where the students get a total of 3 hrs to answer the question , i want to save the value of the countdown timer in the database so that if  there is a power failure then the timer can again start from the last saved value

Comment: Do you even need ajax? Log the time when the page loads, then you can compare it on the next page load (unless there are start/pause controls) when they return. Might need an `onunload` ajax call though.. really depends on how perfect and 'safe' a solution you want

Comment: Thanks a lot , it seems o be a good solution

Answer (score 0):

You should track the date when the timer starts (which can be a mysql datetime column) and now you can calculate the time which is past.

Here an example for calculate the time:

```
<?php
// load the date from the database
$timeDate = strottime($data['created_at']);
$now = time();
$diff = $now - $timeDate;

// $diff is now an \DateInterval
if ($diff > 10800) { // If the difference more than 3 hours
   // show some errors or do whatever you want :)
}
```